# Django Blog - edit/delete user comments functions help needed pls

Tags: python, django

I am quite new to software development and quite new to django and python. I am currently working on a project to develop blog, which needs to have functions for users to edit and delete their own comments.

Whilst I have developed the blog, I am struggling with getting the functions correctly coded and wired up to URLS file.

I have added icons below user comments to either delete or edit their comments.

My question is what is the correct code for creating functions in views file and also how can i correctly wire it up to URL file. I am not sure if I am missing any packages to get the edit/delete functionality developed.

I have enclosed details of my model, views and urls files.
Any guidance/support will be highly appreciated.

Models file

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from cloudinary.models import CloudinaryField

STATUS = ((0, "Draft"), (1, "Published"))

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="blog_posts")
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    featured_image = CloudinaryField('image', default='placeholder')
    excerpt = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blog_likes', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def number_of_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()

class Comment(models.Model):
    
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Comment {self.body} by {self.name}"
```

Views file

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, reverse
from django.views import generic, View
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Post
from .forms import CommentForm


class PostList(generic.ListView):
    model = Post
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')
    template_name = 'index.html'
    paginate_by = 4


class PostDetail(View):

    def get(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1)
        post = get_object_or_404(queryset, slug=slug)
        comments = post.comments.filter(approved=True).order_by("-created_on")
        liked = False
        if post.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True

        return render(
            request,
            "post_detail.html",
            {
                "post": post,
                "comments": comments,
                "commented": False,
                "liked": liked,
                "comment_form": CommentForm()
            },
        )

    def post(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1)
        post = get_object_or_404(queryset, slug=slug)
        comments = post.comments.filter(approved=True).order_by("-created_on")
        liked = False
        if post.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True

        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)

        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comment_form.instance.email = request.user.email
            comment_form.instance.name = request.user.username
            comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
        else:
            comment_form = CommentForm()

        return render(
            request,
            "post_detail.html",
            {
                "post": post,
                "comments": comments,
                "commented": True,
                "liked": liked,
                "comment_form": CommentForm()
            },
        )

class PostLike(View):

    def post(self, request, slug):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)

        if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            post.likes.remove(request.user)
        else:
            post.likes.add(request.user)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post_detail', args=[slug]))
```

Urls file

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path


urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.PostList.as_view(), name="home"),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('like/<slug:slug>', views.PostLike.as_view(), name='post_like'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using class based views, there are generic views already set up for Updating and Deleting:  See the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/

Your icons can simply be links to those views, and the rest is handled for you.  You don't need to add complexity to your PostDetails view.

Comment: thank you very much, will have a look in the django documentation as per your suggestion.

Comment: hi there, I have gone through the documentation but still struggling to come up with the right code in view,url to get the delete/update working. Would you be able to share a view please as to how you would code deletions and updates. I am not looking for someone to do it for me but I am really struggling to get it right

Comment: There's a good demo of how to set up a basic implementation including views.py and url.py examples at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/class-based-generic-views-django-create-retrieve-update-delete/   You just need to modify the update and delete versions for your Comment model